# PHPExcel calculate formula cell and format currency

Tags: php, phpexcel

Now I'm reading an excel file and showing it on a html table.
like this:

```
 <?php 
 function load_table(){
    require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("SampleData.xlsx");
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5

    echo '<table>' . "\n";
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
      echo '<tr>' . "\n";

      for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        echo '<td>';
        echo  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();     
        echo '</td>' . "\n";

      }

      echo '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
    echo '</table>' . "\n";
}
  ?>
```

Sometimes the cell content is a formula. I'd like to calculate it and `echo` the result (just like excel does).  I tried the code below but I got the following error:
`Warning: Illegal string offset 'value' in...`

```
echo  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
```

I also tried something like:

```
echo  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getOldCalculatedValue();
```

This one worked, but I do not want to use `GetOldCalculatedValue` because:

> getOldCalculatedValues() reads the value as it was last calculated by MS Excel (if available) though you can't guarantee it will always be there, or be correct if it is (you can disable autocalculation in MS Excel, or it won't be set if loading a CSV file); while getCalculatedValue() actually recalculates the value within PHPExcel itself.

Also I used `echo` to print just the formula string and it appears to be just fine:

```
echo $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
```

Fórmula printed:
`=F2*E2 
=F3*E3 
=F4*E4 
=F14*E14 ...`

So how could I get the result of the formula and ALSO format it as currency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards cell formatting:

The cell won't have any format if you use

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

because you're specifically telling PHPExcel ***not*** to load cell formats. Don't set readDataOnly to true if you want to read formats

As regards the other part of your question, if you're getting an error when you call

```
echo  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
```

then it might be useful to say what the formula is

```
echo  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
```

should tell you the formula, so perhaps you might consider adding that to your question, because it's quite useful to know if you want help

Comment: Hello Mark, what a honor ! when I echo  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();` it prints the formula perfect. But I'd like to find a way to print its result instead. Already set `ReadDataOnly(false);`` but the error continues. Please help '-'

Comment: It's possible that there's a problem with the formula, if you're getting an error when you call `getCalculatedValue();`, so it might be useful to know what that formula is

Comment: Examples: `=F2*E2 , =F3*E3, =F9*E9 ...`. When I open the excel file itself the results are fine.

Comment: Well those formulae shouldn't cause any problems: what version of PHPExcel are you running?

Comment: I am using `PHPExcel 1.7.6`. Because when I download the file from github wich is the version 1.9, I cant find the `PHPExcel.php` inside the zip.

Comment: 1.7.6 is pretty old, and shouldn't be used anymore: 1.8.1 is the latest tagged production release... Don't use the 1.9 branch, the big warning in the README should tell you that it is a highly unstable branch at the moment